# Android: How to make the keypad always visible?

Tags: android, keypad

In android, how do we make the device keypad always visible in the application? The top portion displays the content the application wants to render and bottom portion displays the keypad always.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Add android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" to your activity in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" />
```

In my test app this shows the keyboard on starting of the application although it isn't fixed there but can be dismissed by pressing the back button.

To make sure the keyboard is always visible you might have to create your own keyboard as part of the UI of your application. Here is a tutorial to show you how to do this with KeyboardView: http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm

Comment: I tried to use the android  source code and can drag the keyboard around but not sure which part I should modify to disable it from hiding. I am looking at the class under LatinIME.java. I tried adding the inputView from that google code to a WindowManager.addView.

Comment: @Simon See my update to my answer. You probably want to use KeyboardView.

Answer (score 12):

You must have an `EditText` in your layout and that need to extent `EditText` base class. then Override `onKeyPreIme()` method, and return *True*. Now your keyboard will be always visible and can't be dismissed by Back key.

**Caution**: Because of your `onKeyPreIme()` method returns `true` you can't exit your app using back key.

Example:

```
public class CustomEdit extends EditText {

    public CustomEdit(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("Log", "onKeyPreIme");
        return true;
        //return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

[onKeyPreIme() - Android developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onKeyPreIme%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29)

Answer (score 2):

I found a way that works for me to keep the soft keyboard visible after an edit in my `myEditText` field of class `EditText`. The trick is to override the `onEditorAction` method so that it returns `true`

```
  myEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {                     
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
      return true;
    }       
  });
```

or else have `onEditorAction` return `true` only after the "Done" key-click ([`IME_ACTION_DONE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html)) otherwise `false`

```
  myEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {                     
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
      if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "IME_ACTION_DONE");
        return true;    
      }
      return false;
    }       
  });
```

(see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19617831) on the `onEditorAction` method)

Adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible` to the Manifest file helped to have the soft keyboard shown at activity start but it didn't prevent it from disappearing again whenever the "Done" key was clicked after an edit.