# Android show digits keypad on activity start

Tags: android, keyboard, digits, alphabet

As stated in the title, how do I call the digits keypad on activity start? Right now I have this:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

in OnCreate.
But this is just a normal full keyboard with letters.

Comment: Did you try this one: android:inputType="number"  in your xml-layout?

Comment: Yeah but it doesn't work... note I have no edittext box etc, just a linear layout with listview. But I want the keypad to appear.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509719/android-how-to-make-the-keypad-always-visible

Comment: hey thank I have seen that already. But what I really need is the numeric/digits keypad. That one only solves for the normal keyboard

Answer (score 0):

this was my aproach.

To show it

InputMethodManager lIMManager

```
lIMManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(this.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
lIMManager.getInputMethodList();
lIMManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

To hide it

```
mIMManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtPin.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

The down side is that you have to close it by hand( it wont even close if you close the app)
Hope this helps!
Regards