# Android: how do I keep the keyboard up all the time

Tags: android, keyboard, back-button

I'm trying to keep the keyboard up, at all times.  I don't want the back button to hide it.
I don't want anything to hide it.

I've dumped android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" in the manifest, though it seems the team that built this feature should google the definition of "always"

When I press the back button on my app it hides the keyboard.

Is there a way to catch and kill the first back button click, or pass it up to the activity and not have the keyboard hide?

EDIT

---

Overriding any of these and putting break points on every line shows me one thing, none of these get called.  The keyboard is hidden, and my activity didn't have have a clue.

```
 public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
 public boolean onKeyMultiple(int keyCode, int repeatCount, KeyEvent event){
 public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
 public void onBackPressed() {
```

Comment: +1 **When I press the back button on my app it hides the keyboard**

Comment: Yeah.. same here.. Still poking at how to "disable" that "feature"

Comment: Answer is on another question here ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/12243804/507950

Answer (score 0):

*Is there a way to catch and kill the first back button click, or pass it up to the activity and not have the keyboard hide?*

Yes. Just use the following code:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       //do nothing,hence avoiding the soft keyboard from hiding
       return;
    }
```

Comment: Nope.. keyboard catches it before that gets called. The keyboard goes away.

Comment: Yeah.. that's where I got the, alwaysvisible lie.. The idea of writing my own graffiti interpreter is ugly, and sometimes, I like to use swipe, or the stock keyboard.   I was hoping the topic had moved on, from 2009.

Comment: Also, much of the conversation is about how to show the keyboard.  Alwaysvisible does manage to show the keyboard when I start the app.  When I hit the back button however, the keyboard goes away.  I don't want it to goaway.  I want the app to bring the user back a screen (or out of my app)