# Permanent keyboard visibility for my application

Tags: android, static, keyboard, visibility

I am trying to make an android application for Tablet. I need to display keyboard above all my activities by default and i don't need to hide the keyboard when user presses back key.
Any idea to make it work???

**EDIT:** Solved by using a custom EditText

```
    public class CustomEdit extends EditText {

public CustomEdit(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e("Log", "onKeyPreIme");
    return true;
    //return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event);
}
```

}

[Android: How to make the keypad always visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12243804/1004605)

Comment: This is a nice break in what a user expects as default functionality, so I'm going to have to ask why you want to do this?

Comment: Our client says that they need it, that's why.

Answer (score 2):

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
```

And also add this to catch the backButton being pressed and do nothing on it.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // do nothing
        return;

    }
```

Also,

```
mEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {


            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
                     // again do nothing

              return false;
                  } };
```

***NOTE :*** Only adding *`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"`* will show the keyboard initially but can be dismissed by pressing the BackButton if you don't override the backButton.

Answer (score 2):

you could use this in your manifest,  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" for all you activity.

Comment: Tried before, not working. keyboard hides on back key. I need a permanent keyboard. anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: @FavasKv : Yes, and that is why you would need to override the BackButton.

Comment: @swayam Activities onBackPressed() method does not calls when keyboard is visible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940127/intercept-back-button-from-soft-keyboard

Answer (score 1):

i've implemented this in one of my application.
u need following code.

```
// getting InputMethodManager system service which will handle aur
        // keyboard event
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        // restartInput method will restart the current view with its updated 
        // content. here medtName is a EditText
        imm.restartInput(medtName);

        // toggleSoftInput will responsible for showing or hiding device
        // keyboard.
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

Comment: Please consider upvoting instead of adding the same code as your answer. Cheers. :)