# How to get Keypad to be displayed on app startup

Tags: android, keypad

As a part of my application, I want the android default keypad to be displayed on starting of the application, I got the following code from the forum, but it is not working.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    InputMethodManager imm;
    imm = = (InputMethodManager) gettSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, inputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

Please let me know, if I am doing anything wrong, or is there any other way to accomplish the functionality.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there an `EditText` in the `Activity`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar. But it requires an EditText in the layout.

```
private EditText editText;

void showKeyboard() {
    this.editText.requestFocus();
    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    mgr.showSoftInput(this.editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `EditText` in the layout, use this:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mgr.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Alternatively, if you **don't** have an `EditText` in the layout and still need to show the Soft Keyboard, use this:

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

Note: for the second alternative, the import necessary for the `LayoutParams` is:`import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to Change in your `manifest.xml` file

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" />
```

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509719/android-how-to-make-the-keypad-always-visible) for Details.

By Doing this Device's Keyboard will be open when load Application.