# Keep the numeric keypad open through out activity life

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-keypad

I have a screen which asks user to enter PIN. 
I have 4 separate boxes & each box will have only one digit.
So I want to keep the Numeric keypad open through out the life of an activity.
I am able to force keypad open up on activity starts. But On presses back button it gets hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you set this as part of your activity section on your manifest file :

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"
```

you could try something like this :

```
public class EditView extends EditText {

    public EditView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you try adjustResize

Comment: `adjustResize` also hides the keypad on Back Button pressed

Comment: Do you have 4 activities for the 4 boxes ?

Comment: Nope Only one activity.....And through out this activity I need the keypad open...

Comment: You could refer to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509719/android-how-to-make-the-keypad-always-visible

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24170/discussion-between-lokoko-and-hemu)