# How to NOT close keyboard when DONE on keyboard is pressed

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

When the user presses "Done" on the soft keyboard, the keyboard closes. I want it so that it will only close if a certain condition is true (eg. the password was entered correctly).

This is my code (sets up a listener for when the "Done" button is pressed):

```
final EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
et.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() 
{        
   @Override
   public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
   {
      if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
      {
         if (et.getText().toString().equals(password)) // they entered correct
         {
             // log them in
         }
         else
         {
             // bring up the keyboard
             getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);

             Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Incorrect.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
      }
      return false;
   }
});
```

I realize that the reason this doesn't work is probably because it runs this code *before* it actually closes the soft keyboard on its own, but that's why I need help. I don't know another way.

A possible topic for answers could be working with:

```
activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
```

and that sort of thing, but I don't know for sure.

---

**SOLUTION:**

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
et.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() 
{        
  @Override
  public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
  {
    if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
    {
       if (et.getText().toString().equals(password)) // they entered correct
       {
           // log them in
           return false; // close the keyboard
       }
       else
       {
           Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Incorrect.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           return true; // keep the keyboard up
       }
    }
    // if you don't have the return statements in the if structure above, you
    // could put return true; here to always keep the keyboard up when the "DONE"
    // action is pressed. But with the return statements above, it doesn't matter
    return false; // or return true
  }
});
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

if your return `true` from your `onEditorAction` method, action is not going to be handled again. In this case you can return `true` to not hide keyboard when action is `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE`.

Comment: Great answer. I couldn't find any documentation on what the method is supposed to return.

Comment: But then imeOption of keyboard changes