# Prevent Soft Keyboard from hiding on button click

Tags: android

I have an EditText with a button next to it. The button adds the keyword from the EditText to a list and clears the EditText so that the user can enter another keyword. Every time the button is pressed, the keyboard goes away. I have tried `android:focusable="false"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` on the button and I have tried `editText.requestFocus()` in the button on click method. The keyboard still disappears. The behavior I want can be seen in the Google Messenger app and the Out of Milk app (and probably many other todo list apps).

Comment: have you also tried adding `editText.requestFocus()` at last line of button click event ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna that doesn't work

Comment: The keyboard is already gone before the button click method is called. An ideal solution would prevent the keyboard from hiding by that time.

Comment: How is it possible ? you mean keyboard hides while writing something ?

Comment: No. I set a breakpoint in the button click method.

Comment: I simply tested like you said and working properly, So that I need to see your codes. Can you please post that.

Comment: Post your code what exactly you doing???

Comment: you could choice this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509719/android-how-to-make-the-keypad-always-visible

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet, but I've used the first code block in an app I have for adding a filter window (consisting of an edit text, a set of toggle buttons and a set of check boxes) in a click listener and showing the keyboard. I assume it would work with the text view already visible. Just getting focus doesn't open the keyboard automatically, or else it didn't for me either.

http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html

Will add code tomorrow if still open.

Answer (score 0):

I had an override `dispatchTouchEvent` in my activity to do the exact opposite thing. I wanted the keyboard to disappear when tapping outside of another EditText. I could share the code but I think it is arbitrary. In the end, it helped a lot to really understand touch events by reading [this article](http://balpha.de/2013/07/android-development-what-i-wish-i-had-known-earlier/).