# How to always show soft keyboard and do not let it be closed?

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard, android-keypad, window-soft-input-mode

I want to know 2 things

1. how to always show soft keyboard and do not let it be closed ( even when back or OK button was pressed ) ?
2. and how can I get an input from it?

I have already tried this code:

```
    EditText yourEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed);
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```

with these variants:

1. `imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);`
2. `imm.toggleSoftInputFromWindow( yourEditText.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);`
3. `imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);`

Comment: you can check this. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1510005/4344623). Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"` in to `AndroidManifest.xml` file

**Like this:**

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" />  // OR stateVisible
```

> If that activity having `EditText` so when ever Activity will start
>   your Keyboard automatically open

If you want to still open `Keyboad` after use done any operation then do this via **programetically**

```
InputMethodManager imm =
    (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(
    linearLayout.getApplicationWindowToken(),
    InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

**OR**

**To Show Soft Keyboard**

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
     getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(EDITABLE_VIEW,
     InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

**OR**

**`EDITABLE_VIEW` can be any view which has focus on screen like**

```
mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
     getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(mEditText ,
     InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

**OR**

```
((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInputFromInputMethod(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

**[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)**

Comment: Yeap, they all get closed after pressing the back or ok button.

Comment: do u try also putting  `<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" />` this and apply all three way and let me know if any changes

Comment: Yes, sure, but no result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161267/discussion-between-nd1010-and-abrutsze).